# Как исключить канал из группы на отправку сообщения djnago channels?

Tags: django, django-channels

self.channel_name - имя какого-то канала, мне надо чтобы определенный канал был исключен из получения сообщений, как это сделать?

```
# так добавляю новые каналы в группе chat
await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                'chat',
                self.channel_name
            )
# рассылка сообщений по каналам для этой группы 
await self.send_json(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления канала с группы нужно использовать `group_discard`

```
await self.channel_layer.group_discard('chat', self.channel_name)
```